# Split multiple data cells per row <td> in single data cell per row - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with multiple data cells per row, like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>content 1</td>
            <td>content 2</td>
            <td>content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">content 4</td>
            <td>content 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">content 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I split all  elements in independent rows using jQuery. To be be more specific the result will have to be like this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>content 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var $tbody = $('tbody'), $tds = $tbody.find('td:not(:first)').detach();
$tbody.find('tr:not(:has(td))').remove()
$tds.removeAttr('colspan').wrap('<tr />').parent().appendTo('tbody');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D3S35/)

Comment: @Cherniv ya missed that... fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("table tr").find("td").each(function(){
$("table tbody").append("<tr><td>"+$(this).text()+"</td></tr>");
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7PKP/2/)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var new_trs="";
> $('td').each(function(){
>     new_trs += "<tr><td>"+this.innerHTML"</td></tr>";
> ```
>
> });$('tbody').html(new_trs);

Answer (score 0):

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/puMsC/1/)**

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var child;
    $("td").each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('colspan');
        child+="<tr>"+$(this)[0].outerHTML+"</tr>";
    });
    $('tbody').html(child);
});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXxB4/)

```
var $newRows = '';
$('td').each(function (thisTd, index) {
    $newRows += '<tr><td>' + $(this).text() + '</td></tr>';
});
$('#t-body').html($newRows);
```